# Why do I get the error "send() got an unexpected keyword argument" when running a command with my selfbot?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a Selfbot in Python. I have this command to DM all users in a guild. In a guild I do `{prefix}dmall (message)` and then send it and get this error.

```
@knife.command()        # dms all guild users
async def dmall(ctx):
    for user in ctx.guild.members:
        await user.send(message=ctx.message)
```

```
Ignoring exception in command dmall:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\me\OneDrive\Desktop\endless sb template\main.py", line 104, in dmall
    await user.send(message=ctx.message)
TypeError: send() got an unexpected keyword argument 'message'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: send() got an unexpected keyword argument 'message'
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the keyword message in the line `await user.send(message=ctx.message)`

I don't know what you're trying to do here but try this:-

```
@knife.command()        
async def dmall(ctx):
    for user in ctx.guild.members:
        await user.send(ctx.message)
```